# Preferred inter-pod affinity never being respected in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `jenkins` pod, having the label `app: jenkins-master`

This resides on `jenkins` namespace.

I want an `nginx` pod of a deployment (on another namespace, `default`) to be collocated to the above pod.

So I add the following in its spec:

```
spec:
  affinity:
    podAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          namespaces:
            - all
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values:
              - jenkins-master
          topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/os"
```

I have a GKE cluster of 8 nodes.

Out of 5-6 times I have created/deleted the deployment, the `nginx` pod actually **never** landed on the same node as `jenkins-master`.

I know it is **`preferred`** scheduling, but is this behavior normal?

Working on GKE with `"v1.15.9-gke.24"`

**edit 1**: I have changed the `topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"` as suggested in a couple of answers below but that didn't help much either.

**edit 2**: These are the allocated resources for the node that `jenkins-master` pod is scheduled on

```
  Resource                   Requests      Limits
  cpu                        1691m (43%)   5013m (127%)
  memory                     4456Mi (33%)  8902Mi (66%)
```

Since scheduling is based on requests, I don't understand how the following deployment fails to collocate, the requests I am making are minimal

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "100m"
   requests:
    memory: "100Mi"
    cpu: "50m"
```

Comment: Does the same happen when you change from `preffered` to `required`? By design scheduler should deploy pods with `topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"` on same node whenever it is possible. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#always-co-located-in-the-same-node

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake using the `topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/os"` which is used if you are mixing operating systems in your cluster (for example: mixing Linux and Windows nodes).

You should be using: `topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"`, where Kubelet populates this label with the hostname.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know that `topology` refers to some labels that are given to the nodes automatically upon initialization of the cluster.

So, `topology` groups nodes as one (through these labels), so when you say `topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/os"`, you are saying choose a node that is part of this group, and schedule the pod on it. Since probably all your nodes have the same OS, to your scheduler it is a valid node to run on. So, yes, it is intended behavior.

Note that this is still a preference, but it will still try to schedule on the right node, if there are enough resources.

What you have to do is what is suggesting omricoco; `topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"`. You need to let the scheduler group by hostname, so you will have only 1 node per group, and the pod to be scheduled will be on the same node.

Comment: My question is the following: even if there are multiple nodes matching the `topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/os"` constraint, why doesn't the node satisfying the label matching condition prevail?

Comment: btw changing to `topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"` didn't help much

Comment: all your nodes have the same label, so all of them are satisfying. what do you mean didn't help? there was room and it didn't get scheduled there? Then set up a requirement.